# Show that $\langle f_n \rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence, where $f_n=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Show that $\langle f_n \rangle$, where $$f_n=1-1/2+1/3-1/4+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$ is a Cauchy sequence.

My attempt:

Consider $$|f_{2m}-f_m| = \left| \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m+2}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{2m-1}}{2m} \right| \le \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{1}{m+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2m}$$

But this is going in the direction of proving that the given sequence is not a Cauchy sequence.  Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$` in the title, `$...$` is just fine. On another note, this is not your homework support center, you have asked two very similar questions in the course of 5 minutes…

Comment: @Christoph apologies. i am just trying to learn .

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article on alternating series.  There's a straightforward way to make this estimate described therein.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series

Comment: Why is it sufficient to compare $f_m$ and $f_{2m}$ (and not $f_m$ and $f_n$ in general)?

Answer (score 3):

$$m\geqslant n\implies\left|f_m-f_n\right|\leqslant\frac1{n+1}$$

Comment: how to get this inequality ?

Comment: Every partial sum of an *alternating series* (please check this term) is bounded in absolute value by the first term.

Answer (score 3):

What's going wrong is that you are using the triangle equality too much.  This is an alternating series which does not converge absolutely so if you lose the signs of course it will not converge.  What I suggest trying is to group the terms in the partial sums "by two" so that all the terms are positive (or, all the terms are negative) and then the series will look more like the series for summing $\frac{1}{n^2}$.  Of course then you have to show this series converges but this is done in many textbooks, e.g. Rudin.

Of course you could apply the alternating series test to see that it converges and is thus Cauchy but I assume you want something more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

$|f_{m+p}-f_m| = \left| \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m+2}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{m+p-1}}{m+p} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{1}}{m+2}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{m+p} \right| $

If $p$ is odd, then $|f_{m+p}-f_m| =\left| \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{1}}{m+2}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{m+p} \right|=\left| \bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+3}-\frac{1}{m+4}\bigg)+\dots+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-2} -\frac{1}{m+p-1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{m+p}\right|=\bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+3}-\frac{1}{m+4}\bigg)+\dots+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-2} -\frac{1}{m+p-1}\bigg)+\frac{1}{m+p}=\frac{1}{m+1}-\bigg(\frac{1}{m+2}-\frac{1}{m+3}\bigg)-\dots-\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-1} -\frac{1}{m+p}\bigg)< \frac{1}{m+1} $

(because all the terms except the first are all negative)

If $p$ is even, then$|f_{m+p}-f_m| =\left| \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^{1}}{m+2}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{m+p} \right|=\left| \bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+3}-\frac{1}{m+4}\bigg)+\dots+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-1} -\frac{1}{m+p}\bigg)\right|=\bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+3}-\frac{1}{m+4}\bigg)+\dots+\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-1} -\frac{1}{m+p}\bigg)=\frac{1}{m+1}-\bigg(\frac{1}{m+2}-\frac{1}{m+3}\bigg)-\dots-\bigg(\frac{1}{m+p-2} -\frac{1}{m+p-1}\bigg)-\frac{1}{m+p}< \frac{1}{m+1} $

So for any $m, p>0, |f_{m+p}-f_m|\leq \frac{1}{m+1},$ this implies that $f_m$ is Cauchy sequence.

Comment: How does one get rid of the absolute values? Why is it sufficient to compare $f_m$ and $f_{2m}$ (and not $f_m$ and $f_n$ in general)?

Comment: I just tended to show @ user148117 how to deal with the inequality , more rigorously, we should use $f_n$ and $f_m$.

Comment: and all the sum of terms except the first one is smaller than first term.

Comment: These considerations should be explicitly (and rigorously...) spelled out in the answer, which, at the moment, makes believe that some not-so-obvious properties at the heart of the question are direct.

Comment: Ok, I change it now.

Comment: Because all the terms except the first are negative.

Comment: Now it works. *Bravo*.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your patient instruction.

Comment: @Did can you tell me is this correct? For n,m>N, $|S_n-S_m| < |\frac {1}{m+1}| +|\frac {1}{m+2}|+...+|\frac {1}{m+(n-m)}| < \frac {1}{N}*(n-m) $

Now take N so large that $1/N \to 0, n-m $is finite(can i say this n-m finite and take so large N that n-m < N and N$\to \infty$ )

Kindly reply as i am learning things in real analysis, also by going thru various posts in this forum

Comment: @anirudhb This is incorrect. For more details, please post a separate question.

Comment: @Did people shout at me if i raise separate Qn by marking it as duplicate. It will greatly help me if u post details here itself. Already added kudos to ur post above.

I think my case will fail when $n = 2N^2, m = N^2$. Not able to get anythought except the above way. But if n-m = 1 ie., $|S_n-S_{n-1}|=(1/n)< \epsilon$ is strightforward. But how to take forward from here?

Answer (score 1):

One answer was not written here down. It is written in a way called "Mathematics made difficult".

Consider the infinite series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$. This is a convergent series as it is an alternating series and its $n$-th term $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

$f_n = n$-th partial sum $= 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n}$. The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers. Hence it is Cauchy sequence.